# doesnt display anything on the browser when using filename.php

Tags: php, html

it produces output when it is saved as filename.html
but when i try to change it to filename.php

then open the link in the brown using filename.php
it doesnt produce output anymore

NOTE: i removed some of the code too long

```
       <?php
echo"
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <script>
        print code requirement
        function printpage()
        {
        window.print();
        }
        </script>
        print code requirement


        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>WildFlowers by FCT</title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <style type="text/css">

        #wrapper #header-wrapper #header h1 a strong {
            font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            size: '100';
            font-size: 40px;
        </body>
        </html>

";
        ?>
```

Comment: **Don't mix HTML and PHP**. Use templates for that. [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/), just choose any. **HTML** is the **V** in **MVC**, **PHP** is the **C** (and/or **M**) (and your DB and/or your model classes the **M**). Keep those separate whenever possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove `<?php` and `?>`. Between these two tags there must be php-code and no html.

Edit: Maybe no errors are reported, because your server is configured to suppress errors.

Comment: but i need php for mysql but since i used macromedia for designing there is html

Comment: Yes, you can use php inside the php-tags, e.g. `<div class="data"><?php echo $var; ?></div>`

Answer (score 3):

Put some space after the echo..And use single quote['] insted of double.And change all single quotes from your code to double quote.(")

eg: -

```
<?php echo '
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body> Bla bla bla
    </body>
</html>';
?>
```

The problem in your code is, you just started the codes with double quote.So the PHP server consider the next double quote is the closing of the echo statement.So there is nothing to print inside the first two double quote.But if you take the page source, you can see

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you open PHP tag at the beginning of file:

```
<?php
```

Close it before your HTML markup:

```
<?php
    // your php code
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not have html in your php tags, if you want to use html you have to end the close your php first so something like this:

```
<?php
// php code here
?>

html code here

<?php
// php here
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If You need to write html inside php code use the echo statement.
ex:

```
<?php echo"
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        //your code here
    </body>
</html>";
?>
```

Comment: You can't just add html elements inside php tags. If you need to do like that follow my answer. put html tags inside echo statement and turn html " to ' . And you need to run php files in wamp server.